# How to avoid a text body-addressee clash on scrlttr2 letter when multiple addressees are listed?

Tags: positioning, koma-script, letters, scrlttr2

In trying to use the scrlttr2 package, with a letter address to lots of multiple parties, there is clash/crash between the body of the letter, and those to whom the letter is addressed. In other words the body of the letter, including the subject is printed on top of the last two of the four addresses.

This ends up looking very ugly:  [image]

How do I fix this so that I can still use the scrlttr2 letter class to compose my letter?

Help with this would be mucho appreciated.

```
\documentclass[ 
fontsize=11pt, paper=a4, parskip=half, enlargefirstpage=on, % More space                        on first page 
fromalign=right, % PLacement of name in letter head 
fromphone=on, % Turn on phone number of sender 
fromrule=aftername, % Rule after sender name in letter head 
addrfield=on, % Address field for envelope with window 
backaddress=off, % Sender address in this window 
subject=beforeopening, % Placement of subject 
locfield=narrow, % Additional field for sender 
foldmarks=off, % Print foldmarks
]{scrlttr2} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{bookman} 
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\setkomafont{fromname}{\sffamily } 
\setkomafont{fromaddress}{\sffamily}%% statt \small 
\setkomafont{pagenumber}{\sffamily} 
\setkomafont{subject}{\bfseries} 
\setkomafont{backaddress}{\mdseries} 
\LoadLetterOption{DIN} 
\setkomavar{fromname}{LAW OFFICE OF CHEET M. LIKELY} 
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{10723 Brooke Avenue, Suite 245\\Forest Hills, New York  11375} 
\setkomavar{fromphone}{555.878.6202} 
\setkomavar{fromemail}{from.name@mail.com}         \setkomavar{backaddressseparator}             {\enspace\textperiodcentered\enspace} 
\setkomavar{signature}{Bill U. Lotts,     Esq.} 
\setkomavar{place}{} 
\setkomavar{date}{\today} 
\setkomavar{enclseparator}{: } 

\begin{letter}{HIGHSTUFF BRYNYARD, ESQ.
BYRNYARD LAW OFFICES, PLLC.
4 WEST GATE\\
FURMANVILLE, NY 11735 \vskip.2in JOSEPH M. DSGRIBLE, ESQ.\\
DSGRIBLE DSGRIBLE \& DSGRIBLE\\
555 STUFFIT AVE \\
HARDHEART CITY, NY 11530\\
(555) 222-2800 \vskip.2in  JOSEPH F. PYZKOFF, ESQ.\\
PYZKOFF, PYZKOFF & PYZKOFF\\
500 BYLE COUNTY BLVD. \\
MOSTRUBLE, NY 11735\\
(555) 249-6600 \vskip.2in  JAMES A. POOKA, JR.\\
3320 103RD STREET\\
NUTSO, NY 11361\\
(555) 418-3392}
\setkomavar{subject}{Re:} 
\opening{Dear Sir or Madam:} 
\lipsum[2] 
\closing{Very truly yours,} 
\encl{Papers}
\end{letter} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the output you want to achieve? And why not just create an individual letter for each recipient? By the way: scrlttr2 is based on the german DIN 5008 format, which only defines a quite small area for the recipient address. Have a look at the measures [here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/64/DIN_5008%2C_Form_A.svg). That's why this happens.

Comment: The multiple recipient letter is something that I use when I want to communicate identical contents to a group of people, and to give notice to the entire group that everyone in the group is getting the same letter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your code I get the warning

> address field is 155.80432pt to high

So I would know I have to enlarge both the height of the address field and the space above the refline by 156pt:

```
\makeatletter
  \@addtoplength{toaddrheight}{156pt}% enlarge the height of the address field
  \@addtoplength{refvpos}{156pt}% shift the refline down
\makeatother
```

The so-called pseudolength like `toaddrheight` are explained in the KOMA-Script documentation.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[ 
fontsize=11pt, paper=a4, parskip=half, enlargefirstpage=on, % More space                        on first page 
fromalign=right, % PLacement of name in letter head 
fromphone=on, % Turn on phone number of sender 
fromrule=aftername, % Rule after sender name in letter head 
addrfield=on, % Address field for envelope with window 
backaddress=off, % Sender address in this window 
subject=beforeopening, % Placement of subject 
locfield=narrow, % Additional field for sender 
foldmarks=off, % Print foldmarks
]{scrlttr2} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{bookman} 
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\setkomafont{fromname}{\sffamily } 
\setkomafont{fromaddress}{\sffamily}%% statt \small 
\setkomafont{pagenumber}{\sffamily} 
\setkomafont{subject}{\bfseries} 
\setkomafont{backaddress}{\mdseries} 
%\LoadLetterOption{DIN}% already loaded by the class
\setkomavar{fromname}{LAW OFFICE OF CHEET M. LIKELY} 
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{10723 Brooke Avenue, Suite 245\\Forest Hills, New York  11375} 
\setkomavar{fromphone}{555.878.6202} 
\setkomavar{fromemail}{from.name@mail.com}         
\setkomavar{backaddressseparator}{\enspace\textperiodcentered\enspace} 
\setkomavar{signature}{Bill U. Lotts,     Esq.} 
\setkomavar{place}{} 
\setkomavar{date}{\today} 
\setkomavar{enclseparator}{: } 
\makeatletter
  \@addtoplength{toaddrheight}{156pt}
  \@addtoplength{refvpos}{156pt}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{HIGHSTUFF BRYNYARD, ESQ.
    BYRNYARD LAW OFFICES, PLLC.
    4 WEST GATE\\
    FURMANVILLE, NY 11735\\[.2in]
    JOSEPH M. DSGRIBLE, ESQ.\\
    DSGRIBLE DSGRIBLE \& DSGRIBLE\\
    555 STUFFIT AVE \\
    HARDHEART CITY, NY 11530\\
    (555) 222-2800\\[.2in]
    JOSEPH F. PYZKOFF, ESQ.\\
    PYZKOFF, PYZKOFF \& PYZKOFF\\
    500 BYLE COUNTY BLVD. \\
    MOSTRUBLE, NY 11735\\
    (555) 249-6600\\[.2in]
    JAMES A. POOKA, JR.\\
    3320 103RD STREET\\
    NUTSO, NY 11361\\
    (555) 418-3392}
  \setkomavar{subject}{Re:} 
  \opening{Dear Sir or Madam:} 
  \lipsum[2] 
  \closing{Very truly yours,} 
  \encl{Papers}
\end{letter} 
\end{document}
```

But I think a letter should have an unique `toaddress` and so there should be four letters each with one addressee:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[ 
fontsize=11pt, paper=a4, parskip=half, enlargefirstpage=on, % More space                        on first page 
fromalign=right, % PLacement of name in letter head 
fromphone=on, % Turn on phone number of sender 
fromrule=aftername, % Rule after sender name in letter head 
addrfield=on, % Address field for envelope with window 
backaddress=off, % Sender address in this window 
subject=beforeopening, % Placement of subject 
locfield=narrow, % Additional field for sender 
foldmarks=off, % Print foldmarks
]{scrlttr2} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{bookman} 
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\setkomafont{fromname}{\sffamily } 
\setkomafont{fromaddress}{\sffamily}%% statt \small 
\setkomafont{pagenumber}{\sffamily} 
\setkomafont{subject}{\bfseries} 
\setkomafont{backaddress}{\mdseries} 

\setkomavar{fromname}{LAW OFFICE OF CHEET M. LIKELY} 
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{10723 Brooke Avenue, Suite 245\\Forest Hills, New York  11375} 
\setkomavar{fromphone}{555.878.6202} 
\setkomavar{fromemail}{from.name@mail.com}
\setkomavar{backaddressseparator}{\enspace\textperiodcentered\enspace} 
\setkomavar{signature}{Bill U. Lotts,     Esq.} 
\setkomavar{place}{} 
\setkomavar{date}{\today} 
\setkomavar{enclseparator}{: } 

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\myletter}[1]{%
  \begin{letter}{#1}
    \setkomavar{subject}{Re:}
    \opening{Dear Sir or Madam:} 
    \lipsum[2] 
    \closing{Very truly yours,} 
    \encl{Papers}
    \cc{Recipient 1\\Recipient 2\\Recipient 3\\Recipient 4}
  \end{letter}
}

\myletter{HIGHSTUFF BRYNYARD, ESQ.
    BYRNYARD LAW OFFICES, PLLC.
    4 WEST GATE\\
    FURMANVILLE, NY 11735}
\myletter{
    JOSEPH M. DSGRIBLE, ESQ.\\
    DSGRIBLE DSGRIBLE \& DSGRIBLE\\
    555 STUFFIT AVE \\
    HARDHEART CITY, NY 11530\\
    (555) 222-2800}
\myletter{
    JOSEPH F. PYZKOFF, ESQ.\\
    PYZKOFF, PYZKOFF \& PYZKOFF\\
    500 BYLE COUNTY BLVD. \\
    MOSTRUBLE, NY 11735\\
    (555) 249-6600}
\myletter{
    JAMES A. POOKA, JR.\\
    3320 103RD STREET\\
    NUTSO, NY 11361\\
    (555) 418-3392}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I wish I could give this answer a two thumbs up.  Not only my original question addressed perfectly, but a great alternative.  Just brilliant.